# microsoft.workflow.deployment.config wizard has stopped working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, workflow-manager

**microsoft.workflow.deployment.config** wizard has stopped working

When I am trying to uninstall the Workflow manager it's showing this error and I could not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have tried to uninstall the Workflow Manager software from the control panel directly **before** unconfiguring the Workflow Manager farm!

---

**To uninstall the Workflow Manager properly**, you should **first**, unconfigure it as the following:

- **Leave** the farm from all servers by running the `Workflow Manager Configuration Wizard`. then click **Leave Farm**.
- Delete all the Workflow Manager and Service Bus databases like

  - WFInstanceManagementDB
  - WFManagementDB
  - WFResourceManagementDB
  - SbGatewayDatabase
  - SbManagementDB
  - SBMessageContainer01
- Delete the following registry keys.

  - **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0**  HostConfigurationState
  - **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Service Bus\1.0**  HostConfigurationState

> **Note:** Apply this step on all Workflow Manager farm Servers

You are ready now to **uninstall** the Workflow Manager software from the control panel

- Workflow Manager
- Workflow Manager Client
- Windows Fabric
- Service Bus

---

> **Note:** If you intend to install the Workflow manager again in the same farm, make sure that you have deleted the below folders list
>
> - C:\Program Files\Service Bus
> - C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager
> - C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric